# How to remove a child class from its parents?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to remove a particular child class from many other classes...

HTML:

```
<div id="MainLogs">
    <span class="Pass"></span>
    <span class="Failed"></span> <!-- remove this class -->
    <span class="Information"></span>                             
    <span class="Unknown"></span>
</div>
```

The HTML above I may have other unknown classes but I know for sure, I need to remove `Failed` class...

The data comes from an AJAX call...

```
$.ajax({
    url: LogFile,
    success: function (data) {
        logInformation = $(data).find(".Failed").remove();
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your wording is wrong - you are trying to remove an *element* that has a class.

Comment: Are you trying to remove an *element* or remove a particular *class* from some elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your data is coming back as a string, you'll need to convert it to a jquery object before you can modify it.

```
$.ajax({
    url: LogFile,
    success: function (data) {
        logInformation = $(data);
        logInformation.find(".Failed").remove();
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

if you just want to remove the class and leave the element behind, you can use

```
data.find("span").removeClass("Failed");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching under `data`, search in the document:

```
$("#MainLogs").find(".Failed").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're using jQuery, you could probably do something as simple as this?

```
$('.Failed').remove();
```

Unless you mean you just want to remove the actual class name "Failed" so that class=""?

Answer (score 0):

$("#MainLogs.Failed").remove();

Will remove the span completely. Using **.hide()** instead will take it off the display.